# SPSS errors: what does 'column' mean and how to find them in the syntax?

Tags: spss

Whenever I get an error, it looks like this in Output > Log:

```
Error # 6846 in column 71.  Text: !
A macro expression includes an undefined macro variable or a macro operator
which is not valid within an expression.
Execution of this command stops.
```

Where is `column 71` in my syntax? It only has line numbers, and on the bottom it shows `ln 20 col 10` for example.

Comment: This would be the 71st character in one of your lines. Which line... ? One with macros, I guess

Comment: @horace_vr exactly my question. I have a 100-line macro (from DEFINE to ENDDEFINE), so which line does it mean? I don't understand why it can't simply give me a line number!

Comment: Are all your lines 71+ characters long...? Are you calling other macros inside your macro ?

Comment: @horace_vr no, the lines are varied. And no, this is a stand-alone macro. But the problem is not specific to this file, any syntax error is thrown the same way with columns. SPSS never gives any line number.

Comment: Debugging spss macros can get difficult, especially with the long, complex ones... [MEXPAND and MPRINT](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/spss-statistics/29.0.0?topic=set-mexpand-mprint-subcommands-command) will be helpful, and sometimes dividing the large macro into a few smaller ones makes it easier to maintain and debug. As for line and column numbers - you only get the row number of the first row of the function, and as the whole define-!enddefine sequence is considered as one function, the row number is completely useless :-(

Comment: @eli-k I understand. Thanks. So you are saying if I had the whole macro in one line, then the error is on column 71?

Comment: Truth is I'm not really sure - this feature (column of error) has proven useless time and again, If you try, please let us know of your results :)